# How can I use '--extra-vars' for replicas in Ansible playbooks?

Tags: kubernetes, ansible

I am trying to set a default value of 1 replicas for pod deployment but also I would like to have the option to change the value by using `--extra-vars="pod_replicas=2"`. I have tried the following but it doesn't work for me.

```yaml
vars:
  - pod_replicas: 1

spec:

  replicas: "{{ pod_replicas }}"
```

```
ERROR:
TASK [Create a deployment] 
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "error": 422, "msg": "Failed to patch object: b'{\"kind\":\"Status\",\"apiVersion\":\"v1\",\"metadata\":{},\"status\":\"Failure\",\"m                                                essage\":\" \\\\\"\\\\\" is invalid: patch: Invalid value: \\\\\"{\\\\\\\\\\\\\"apiVersion\\\\\\\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\\\\\\\"apps/v1\\\\\\\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\\\\\\\"kind\\\\\\\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\\\                                                \\\\"Deployment\\\\\\\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\\\\\\\"metadata\\\\\\\\\\\\\":{\\\\\\\\\\\\\"annotations\\\\\\\\\\\\\":{\\\\\\\\\\\\\"deployment.kubernetes.io/revision\\\\\\\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\\\\\\                                                \"1\\\\\\\\\\\\\"},\\\\\\\\\\\\\
(...)
\\"2022-02-14T12:13:38Z\\\\\\\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\\\\\\\"lastTransitionTime\\\\\\\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\\\\\\\"2022-02-14T12:13:33Z\\\\\\\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\\\\\\\"reason\\\\\\\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\\\\                                                \\\"NewReplicaSetAvailable\\\\\\\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\\\\\\\"message\\\\\\\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\\\\\\\"ReplicaSet \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"ovms-deployment-57c9bbdfb8\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\                                                \\\\" has successfully progressed.\\\\\\\\\\\\\"},{\\\\\\\\\\\\\"type\\\\\\\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\\\\\\\"Available\\\\\\\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\\\\\\\"status\\\\\\\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\\\\\\\"True\\\\\\\\                                                \\\\\",\\\\\\\\\\\\\"lastUpdateTime\\\\\\\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\\\\\\\"2022-02-14T14:18:33Z\\\\\\\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\\\\\\\"lastTransitionTime\\\\\\\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\\\\\\\"2022-02-14T14:18:33Z\\\                                                \\\\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\\\\\\\"reason\\\\\\\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\\\\\\\"MinimumReplicasAvailable\\\\\\\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\\\\\\\"message\\\\\\\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\\\\\\\"Deployment has minimum availabili                                                ty.\\\\\\\\\\\\\"}]}}\\\\\": v1.Deployment.Spec: v1.DeploymentSpec.Replicas: readUint32: unexpected character: \\\\ufffd, error found in #10 byte of ...|eplicas\\\\\":\\\\\"1\\\\\",\\                                                \\\"revisi|..., bigger context ...|\\\\\"spec\\\\\":{\\\\\"progressDeadlineSeconds\\\\\":600,\\\\\"replicas\\\\\":\\\\\"1\\\\\",\\\\\"revisionHistoryLimit\\\\\":10,\\\\\"selector\\\\\                                                ":{\\\\\"matchLab|...\",\"field\":\"patch\"}]},\"code\":422}\\n'", "reason": "Unprocessable Entity", "status": 422}
```

Any idea how I can fix this?? Thank you!

Comment: Hi Chris welcome to SO. Please read the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page, and pay especial attention to the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) section. Also, [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71113759/edit) and fix the formatting. Good luck

Comment: sure, i will. thank you @mdaniel

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your question

> How can I use `--extra-vars` in Ansible playbooks?

you may have a look into [Understanding variable precedence](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#understanding-variable-precedence), [Using `-e` extra variables at the command line](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/general_precedence.html#using-e-extra-variables-at-the-command-line) and the following small test setup

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    REPLICAS: 1

  tasks:

  - name: Show value
    debug:
      msg: "{{ REPLICAS }} in {{ REPLICAS | type_debug }}"
```

which will for a run with

```
ansible-playbook vars.yml
```

result into an output of

```
TASK [Show value] ******
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: 1 in int
```

and for a run with

```
ansible-playbook --extra-vars="REPLICAS=2" vars.yml
```

into an output of

```
TASK [Show value] ******
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: 2 in unicode
```

Because of the error message

```
v1.Deployment.Spec: v1.DeploymentSpec.Replicas: readUint32: unexpected character: \\\\ufffd, error found in #10 byte of ...|eplicas\\\\\":\\\\\"1\\\\\"
```

I've introduced the [`type_debug` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#managing-data-types). Maybe it will be necessary to [cast the data type to integer](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#forcing-the-data-type).

```yaml
  - name: Show value
    debug:
      msg: "{{ REPLICAS }} in {{ REPLICAS | int | type_debug }}"
```

**Further Occurences**

- [When I've been tying numeric values from a variable file, they've been resolved as string not numbers](https://github.com/openshift/openshift-restclient-python/issues/321)

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution. Using a json object as an argumet seems to work:

`ansible-playbook --extra-vars '{ "pod_replicas":2 }' <playbook>.yaml`